# How can i write list elements into a separate variable in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to understand the basics of python.
I was trying to figure out how "range" works in lists, so I wrote this code:

```py
words = ["apple", "pinapple", "orange", "stop", "blueberry", "banana"]

for g in range(len(words)) :
    if words[g] == "stop":
        break 
    print (words[g])
```

But I wondered how I could write down the words **"apple", "pinapple",** and **"orange"**, as a separate list?

I tried to set a new variable "test" and add values to it:

```py
words = ["apple", "pinapple", "orange", "stop", "blueberry", "banana"]
test = []
for g in range(len(words)) :
    if words[g] == "stop":
        break 
    test += words[g]
print (test)
```

but for some reason, the words suddenly split into separate **letters**:

['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']

I tried several other ways to change the result, but nothing worked.

*P.S.
I apologize if I wrote the question out of form, this is my first time asking questions here.*

Comment: you can iterate the list directly, ie `for word in words:`; `if word == "stop":`

Comment: You meant to write: `test.append(words[g])`

Comment: The REASON is that `list += x` is the same as `list.extend( x )`, and since your `x` is a string, it gets iterated one element at a time, which means one character at a time.